# Objective-C RestKit no Output

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, rest, restkit

I am using RestKIT to make a GET Request for an API that I want to use. Sadly there is no output. This is the output of the GET Request:

```
{
  "return_code": 0,
  "return_message": "",
  "result": {
    "products_count": 2,
    "product": [
      {
        "id": "2440508995",
        "name": "Long Sweater",
        "description": "This product guarantees warmth in times of need.",
        "price": 8,
        "categories_ids": "73978179"
      },
      {
        "id": "2455113539",
        "name": "Tommy Hilfiger Pants",
        "description": "Exclusive brown pants",
        "price": 13,
        "categories_ids": ""
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Obviously I just want an array, where all the products are stored. This is my method to do that.

```
- (void)loadProducts
{
    RKObjectMapping* resultMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Result class]];
    [resultMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                          @"products_count": @"products_count",

                                                          }];

    RKObjectMapping* productMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Product class]];
    [productMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                         @"id": @"id",
                                                         @"name": @"name",
                                                         @"description": @"description",
                                                         @"price": @"price",
                                                         @"categories_ids": @"categories_ids"
                                                         }];

    [resultMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"product" toKeyPath:@"product" withMapping:productMapping]];



    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:productMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"result" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.api2cart.com/v1.0/product.list.json?api_key=//some keyf&store_key=//some key"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    RKObjectRequestOperation *objectRequestOperation = [[RKObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:@[ responseDescriptor ]];
    [objectRequestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

        RKLogInfo(@"Load collection of Products: %@", mappingResult.array);
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        RKLogError(@"Operation failed with error: %@", error);
    }];

    [objectRequestOperation start];

}
```

I made two classes, one for the result that has a NSNumber "products_count" and one Product class with all the product attitudes. The problem is that even though the connection is made and there is no "error", mappingResult.array is apparently empty. What is the mistake in the code?

Comment: You're using the product mapping in the result response descriptor...

Comment: So I have substitute it with resultMapping?

Comment: That would be the first thing to do. Do you actually need the results container? You could drill down directly to the products with the response descriptor key path...

Comment: OK, I tried both: 1. I changed it to resultMapping and got the error that the Product class is not key-value compliant. 2. I reverse the change (so now its product mapping again )and put as key path response.product; however it tells me that only available key paths are result, return_code and return_message

Comment: `response.product` ? did you mean `result.product` ?

Comment: Yes, Now I get the error that the Product class is not key value compliant

Comment: Well, that's a different problem you'll need to give more details for, but it's probably because you can't set the `description` as it's an existing method name

Comment: Sir, you were correct and have my respect. Now, the output is "<Product: 0x7fe2e3f138e0>", "<Product: 0x7fe2e3f1dac0>", which is still not exactly what I want, but its better than an empty array. You have a suggestion how I can display my products correctly?

Comment: That's just the log. Override `description` if you want the log to contain more details

Comment: ok, I figured it out. If you want, you can post some of your tips as an answer and I will make sure to upvote and accept it as an official answer. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need your `Result` class as the array will already give you the account and you can go direct to the array.

So, your initial problem is that you're using the wrong mapping in the response descriptor. You just need to switch to the result mapping.

You can use the product mapping in the response descriptor, but you should change the key path to `result.products`.

Your product mapping also has an issue because `description` is an existing method on all `NSObject` subclasses so you need to change your usage of it by adding a property called something like `overview` or `title`.